# OpenShift / wildfly-cartridge: How to add own -D arguments to JVM commandline which starts wildfly?

Tags: java, openshift, openshift-cartridge

We run our Java backend application on OpenShift in a scaled application with multiple gears.
We use JGroups to create own communication channels.

Therefore, we need to add some extra parameters to the JVM commandline, which starts the wildfly:
e.g. `-Djgroups.bind_addr=$OPENSHIFT_WILDFLY_IP`

How can we adjust that?
Best regards,
 - badera

Comment: have you looked here? https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-environment-variables.html

Comment: OK, thank you. I think you mean `JAVA_OPTS_EXT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same process that is described here to set the JVM memory higher (https://developers.openshift.com/en/wildfly-jvm-memory.html).

```
rhc env-set JAVA_OPTS_EXT="-Xmx<memory>m" -a <appname>
```